# linking shlwapi.h for to StrCmpLogicalW function

Tags: c++, winapi

Any idea how to port this code from C# to C++?

```
[DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);
```

If I tried this line in my header file in C++, the compiler generated a bunch of error.

```
#include <Shlwapi.h>
```

Comment: Check the Requirements section of the MSDN page for the API - it tells you both the header file AND the library you need to include, at compile- and link-time respectively. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759947(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally got it figured out.  Here is the function.  It is critical that you put the shlwapi.h and vcclr.h header files before any of your own header files if you have any.  That was the issue I have been struggled with.  Don't fully understand why it is.  If anyone have an good explanation, welcome to make comment.  Also, if anyone know how to combine the last three line of code to a single return statement, welcome to add comment.

```
#include "shlwapi.h"  //needed this for StrCmpLogicalW
#include <vcclr.h>   //needed this for PtrtoStringChars
//your own header files

ref class FileInfoNameComparer: public IComparer
    {
    private:

       virtual int Compare( Object^ x, Object^ y ) sealed = IComparer::Compare
       {
            FileInfo^ objX = gcnew FileInfo(x->ToString());
            FileInfo^ objY = gcnew FileInfo(y->ToString());
            pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch1 = PtrToStringChars(objX->Name);
            pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch2 = PtrToStringChars(objY->Name);
            return  StrCmpLogicalW(wch1, wch2);
       }

    };
```

Comment: Presumably you've marked this as the answer because you needed `vcclr.h` to compile all the .net code. Note that 1. Your question did not include any error messages, so we had to guess, 2. Your question made no mention that the code was mixed mode C++/CLI. 3. You have included `shlwapi.h` incorrectly, should be `#include <shlwapi.h>`.

Answer (score 10):

The errors are linker errors because you haven't included the corresponding .lib file, Shlwapi.lib.

You can include the .lib file in the project settings, or alternatively by adding this

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")
```

to, for example, StdAfx.h.

Comment: I actually tried that before I posted this question.  But it did not work seem to work.  And one of the article that I had found did say something about Microsoft do away with it and preferred to use the adding .lib file the project settings.  Are you familiar with the steps to add the .lib file in the project settings?

Comment: a web search will tell you how to do it but the pragma still works